# Why does merge_management only write the last featureclass?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, merge

Here is the  edited code:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

#set the environment settings
env.workspace = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb"
#fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Sub_NVF_*")
output = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb\Merge3FC"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1 # this code overwrites existing output
try:

        FC1 = "Sub_NVF_050413"
        FC2 = "Sub_NVF_052503"
        FC3 = "Sub_NVF_052509"

        fldMap_Mean = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fldMap_NDVI = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fldMap_ID = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

        Mean1 = "M050413"
        Mean2 = "M052503"
        Mean3 = "M052509"
        NDVI1 = "NDVI050413"
        NDVI2 = "NDVI052503"
        NDVI3 = "NDVI052509"
        Fld_ID = "Field_ID"

        fldMap_Mean.addInputField(FC1,Mean1)
        fldMap_Mean.addInputField(FC2, Mean2)
        fldMap_Mean.addInputField(FC3, Mean3)

        fldMap_NDVI.addInputField(FC1, NDVI1)
        fldMap_NDVI.addInputField(FC2, NDVI2)
        fldMap_NDVI.addInputField(FC3, NDVI3)

        fldMap_ID.addInputField(FC1, Fld_ID)
        fldMap_ID.addInputField(FC2, Fld_ID)
        fldMap_ID.addInputField(FC3, Fld_ID)

        #set name of new output field
        Mean_type = fldMap_Mean.outputField
        Mean_type.name = 'Mean'
        Mean_type.aliasName = 'Mean'
        fldMap_Mean.outputField = Mean_type
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fldMap_Mean)

        NDVI_type = fldMap_NDVI.outputField
        NDVI_type.name = 'NDVI'
        NDVI_type.aliasName = 'NDVI'
        fldMap_NDVI.outputField = NDVI_type
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fldMap_NDVI)

        FieldID_type = fldMap_ID.outputField
        FieldID_type.name = 'Field_ID'
        FieldID_type.aliasName = 'Field_ID'
        fldMap_ID.outputField = FieldID_type
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fldMap_ID)

        arcpy.Merge_management([FC1, FC2, FC3], output, fieldMappings)

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Above code works fine. Although mean and NDVI field name are feature class specific, it perfectly does the job. However, when I use for loop and try to read field name as as Mean = "M"+ fname (as shown below), it gives me an error saying "Error in adding input field to field map"

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env


env.workspace = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Sub_NVF_*")
output = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb\MergeAllV1"


try:
    for fc in fcs:
        fcname = fc.split('_', 1)[1]

        fldMap_Mean = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fldMap_ID = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

        Mean = "M"+fcname
        Fld_ID = "Field_ID"

        fldMap_Mean.addInputField(fc, Mean)
        fldMap_ID.addInputField(fc, Fld_ID)


        Mean_type = fldMap_Mean.outputField
        Mean_type.name = 'Mean'
        Mean_type.aliasName = 'Mean'
        fldMap_Mean.outputField = Mean_type
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fldMap_Mean)

        FieldID_type = fldMap_ID.outputField
        FieldID_type.name = 'Field_ID'
        FieldID_type.aliasName = 'Field_ID'
        fldMap_ID.outputField = FieldID_type
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fldMap_ID)

    arcpy.Merge_management(fc, output, fieldMappings)
    print ("done")

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

However, if I try to merge all feature classes using  fields whose name is same  in all files (as shown below), it writes only the last file. Any clue?

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Sub_NVF_*")
output = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb\MergeAll"

try:
    for fc in fcs:

        fldMap_ID = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fldMap_Name = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

        Fld_ID = "Field_ID"
        F_Name = "File_Name"

        fldMap_ID.addInputField(fc, Fld_ID)
        fldMap_Name.addInputField(fc, F_Name)

        FieldID_type = fldMap_ID.outputField
        FieldID_type.name = 'Field_ID'
        FieldID_type.aliasName = 'Field_ID'
        fldMap_ID.outputField = FieldID_type
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fldMap_ID)


        FName_type = fldMap_Name.outputField
        FName_type.name = 'File_Name'
        FName_type.aliasName = 'File_Name'
        fldMap_Name.outputField = FName_type
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fldMap_Name)


    arcpy.Merge_management(fc, output, fieldMappings)


except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: Are you able to cut down your code to a much simpler test that demonstrates your hypothesis that `Merge_management` may not be able to merge multiple files?

Comment: Merge_management should be outside the For loop, not within it.  Just remove 4 spaces in front of Merge_management.

Comment: A nitpicky question, but as I asked on a previous question, why are you calling the `Spatial Analyst` extension, when you are not using any raster functions here?  Don't make your code more complicated than necessary.

Comment: When I applied merge_management to only two feature classes, it did work. However, when I try to merge more than two feature classes (Sub_NVF_*) using for loop, I need to convert field name into variables, hence made Mean = "M"+fname. I guess, it may be the problem. Any idea?

Comment: A couple more comments:  1.  You may get better response if you were to accept answers on your other questions, especially if they've helped you in some way.  2.  Your issue here may be related to the `fc.split` function.  This is splitting 1 time, based on the underscore, leaving 2 parts:  `Sub`, and `NVF_.....`.  The dots represent the number in the feature class.  I think you only want the numbers, not the text as part, so you need to change the split function parameters.  Having the text as well, is affecting the field name creation, and thus messing up the field mapping.

Comment: @Get Spatial: I want both text and number in order to read that field and get the value of that field in merged feature class. Unlike other field names, such as Field_ID, File_Name etc, M... and NDVI... are feature class specific. I need to copy the value of these fields and put these values under "Mean" and "NDVI" field name  of MergeAll feature class.

Comment: You need to move the Merge tool out of the for loop as klewis says. If you look at the Help for this tool it takes as input a LIST of featureclasses. Currently you are supplying one at a time within a for loop, you need to build a list then use that as the input parameter to the merge tool.

Comment: @Hornbydd: Although I moved merge loop out of for loop, it writes only the last file. However, if I explicitly write the name of the files, it does merge these files. Any idea?

Comment: Edit your original question with your new script, so we can see it.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are incorrect for the `merge` tool. In your example, you are adding only a single featureclass `fc`into the merge tool:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(fc, output, fieldMappings)
```

Instead, `merge` requires a list of featureclasses in the inputs parameter, for example:

```
arcpy.Merge_management([featureclass1, featureclass2, featureclass3], output, fieldMappings)
```

Essentially, you need to take `arcpy.Merge_management()` out of the `for` loop and instead feed it a list.